Problem of the black bar adjacent to the front camera in landspace flutter App
Is it possible in flutter to make fullscreen and remove the black bar at the front of the application in landspace mode despite the presence of a front camera inside the screen?
I tried to put Systeme .Chrome and it didn't work.
